# Reading a txt file to array in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga, test-bench

I want to read data from a text file one line at a time. And output at specific instance.
For that I have created to process. The code is used for generating stimulus signals in a test bench.

1st Process:-
Here we are trying to pre-read the data in an array. Also we want to count the no. of data values in one line.

```
data_count: process

variable anc_line       : line;
variable anc_data       : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
variable data_available : boolean;
variable result         : anc_array;
variable count          : integer := 0;
  begin

    file_open(file_anc, "file_anc.txt", read_mode); -- open file
    if read_line_enable = '1' then               -- read line only when it is high
      readline(file_anc, anc_line);              -- read 1st line
      hread(anc_line, result(1), data_available); -- directing readin into the array and checking
                                                  -- data_available boolean. Return false when no data in line remain
      while (data_available = true) loop  -- LOops till the last data in one line is reached
        for i in result'range loop        -- initialising the array
          hread(anc_line, anc_data, data_available); --redaing one data from the line
          result(i) := anc_data;
          data_counter <= count + 1; -- counting the no. of data values in one line. Will be used later
        end loop;
        wait until rising_edge(video_clk);
      end loop;
    end if;

    file_close(file_anc);
    wait;
  end process;
```

2nd Process :-
Want to generate the enable signal on basis of condition. Then compare the hcount with the data_count signal to output the array. Hcout is basically a counter increasing with +1 at every clk. We output the data till the hcoutn is greater than the no. of data values in one line.

```
create_enable: process (video_clk)
begin 
  if rising_edge(video_clk) then -- creating the enable signal
    if  vcount = true and hcount = 0 then  -- checking for conditions
      read_line_enable <= '1';
    else 
      read_line_enable <= '0';
    end if;    

    -- insert data 

    if hcount <= data_counter then -- output data when condition is met

        din_anc <= arr(hcount); -- output data<= array with index using hcoutn
    else                        -- cause hcount increases from 0 to +1 at every clk   
                                -- cycle. 
       din_anc <= "00"&x"20"; -- if hcount gets greater than the amnt of data in one line
                              -- put 20h in output
    end if; 
  end if; 
end process;
```

Problem?

1.Text File doesn't open.
2. Values not being read from txt to array

Summary :-

Can someone help in debugging the code. How can I read a text file to a array and then output it at specif condition. Or maybe you have some other way of doing it?

Comment: What is your simulation environment? Some simulators need a special path to get to the file(s).

Comment: I'm using Model sim 10.3d . But don't worry I was able to read out the data using the basic read text io code. But now when I want to extend my code to include functionalities, it doesn´t work the way I want

Comment: Where is your text file located? You could try to open a file in 'write_mode' and write some stuff to it to see where it will be generated: the file you read should be at the same location. It could be you should put it in the 'work' directory for instance (default library name for modelsim).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The code works. The problem was with the text file character format. Apparently you have such errors in Linux systems. Also, was weird in other instances where I was reading file. So, a tip a for all, if your code is  good but doesn´t work, delete your text file and make it again.